# Using HTML and CSS with QGIS Map Tips?

Tags: qgis, html, css, maptips

I'm trying to make the red text 'un-wrap' itself and use all the room available.

My code is shown below. (I've tried playing with the margin as well but no luck)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please always show code as text rather than pictures so that it is available for future searches by others with similar questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The width of the map tip box is computed without looking at all the data content and is therefore unlikely to fit. You can however set it to a known good size:

```
<style>
h1 {color:red;
 width:300px;}
</style>

<h1>[% "MyField" %]</h1>
```